# Eigenvectors of Normal matrix (orthogonality)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Let's suppose A is normal matrix. I know that the eigenvectors of normal matrix and its conjugate are the same, and that for the fixed eigenvector the eigenvalues are conjugate. Let's fix some $e_1$ normal eigenvector $(||e_1||=1)$, so $Ae_1= λ_1 e_1$ and $A^*e_1=\bar{λ_1}e_1 $.
$$
S_1 = span\{e_1\}
$$
$$
T_1 = \{x : (x,e_1)=0\}
$$
How can I show that there is an eigenvector $e_2$ which belongs to $T_1$?

P.S. I know that if $x∈T_1$ then $Ax∈T_1,A^*x∈T_1$, because
$$
(Ax,e_1)=(x,A^*e_1)=(x,\bar{λ_1}e_1)={λ_1}(x,e_1)=0
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $L_1$ subspace is $A$-invariant, due to the last thing that you prove. And it is a famous theorem about linear operators, that every linear operator has at least one eigenvalue, so there exists some $e_2$ eigenvector which belongs to $T_1$. [Here you can find it](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eanne/WQ2007/mat67-Li-Eigenvectors.pdf) page 5.